# How to use ajax to monitor data from online xml

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, model-view-controller

I'm building an application, one of the requirements is to use AJAX to constantly pull information from an online xml dataset, and get one of the element value, the value is a percentage and I need to make a progress bar out of it .

The url I use for requesting my xml data is something like :

someserver/xml?xpath=(//someattribute)   I get a the value I want, but currently I'm using http request in C# to do it and it is a one time thing, my question is can I use AJAX to pull this type of data frequently ?(like every 3-5 seconds) ?

Another question is about the Query progress bar, I tried the sample here code but it does not display anything on my html file:

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is as simple as the use of a javascript interval:

```
setInterval(
  MakeAjaxCall()
, 3000);
```

The above will  call the `MakeAjaxCall` function every 3 seconds.

Comment: I might have 20 -30 of these running at the same time at in one page in my application , will that be a heavy load for the server ?

Comment: That's an architecture question. I didn't know that was the case. Whether it will be a heavy load for the server or not depends on so much more.